# Run a MATLAB file from Python 2.7 Shell

Tags: python, matlab

Is there a way to run a Matlab.m file from Python 2.7 Shell or a .py code?  I tried using the following code:

```
import os   
os.chdir(r'D:\The_folder_where_the_file_is')                             
os.startfile("The_desired_Matlab_file.m")
```

but then , it just opens the .m file, without running it ( as if when you press F5 in Editor Matlab).What shall i do ?
(I've already downloaded pymat and win32, if that helps)

Comment: An example to run MATLAB with the -r option from Python can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769415/how-do-i-import-a-data-file-as-a-matrix-and-run-a-m-file-from-a-python-script/20770976#20770976)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python can't run `.m` files directly, you need to use matlab or octave. Python can run external commands with the `subprocess.Popen()` function. Try something like this:

```
import subprocess, os
os.chdir(r'D:\The_folder_where_the_file_is')
subprocess.Popen(['matlab','The_desired_Matlab_file.m'])
```

You mentioned you have [pymat](http://claymore.engineer.gvsu.edu/~steriana/Software/pymat.html) installed and want to use that. In that case, the correct way to open a `.m` file is to first use the `pymat.open()` function to start a session, then to run any commands with the `pymat.eval()` function. See the documentation [here](http://claymore.engineer.gvsu.edu/~steriana/Software/pymat.html) for an example and  more details.

Comment: Actually, I'm sorry, i wanted to say Numpy instead of pymat . I tried to install pymat, but it seems to not run in version beyond python 2.2 and right now i am using 2.7 . Thank you very much for your help, i'll look in subprocess library for the proper function

Comment: Subprocess is part of the standard library. You don't have to separately install anything.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I have encounted the same problem,  finally I crack it under this way.
I work on Windows 7 64bit

First, You need put your 'matlab.exe' into your system path 'Path'

Second, try this code

```
    import os, subprocess
    os.chdir(r'D:\the-fold-where-your-m-file-is')
    print os.listdir(os.curdir)
    returnCode = subprocess.call("matlab -r your-m-file-name.m")
    print "Return Code: ", returnCode
```

Hope this answer will help others, thank you !